# What does operator "dot" (.) mean?

Tags: matlab, syntax, operators

Given the code  :

```
 A = [1 2 3; 3 2 1]
 B = A.^2
```

The output :

```
B =

     1     4     9
     9     4     1
```

But if I do this : `B = A^2`

The output is :

```
Error using  ^ 
Inputs must be a scalar and a square matrix.
To compute elementwise POWER, use POWER (.^) instead.
```

What does the operator `.` do exactly ?

Comment: The  `B = A^2` means `B = A * A` and this is illegal matrix operation given the dimension of `A`.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The dot itself is not an operator, `.^` is.

The `.^` is a pointwise¹ (i.e. element-wise) power, as `.*` is the [pointwise product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointwise_product).

> **`.^`**
>   Array power. `A.^B` is the matrix with elements `A(i,j)` to the `B(i,j)` power. The sizes of `A` and `B` must be the same or be compatible.

C.f.

- "Array vs. Matrix Operations": https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/array-vs-matrix-operations.html
- "Pointwise": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointwise
- "Element-Wise Operations": http://www.glue.umd.edu/afs/glue.umd.edu/system/info/olh/Numerical/Matlab_Matrix_Manipulation_Software/Matrix_Vector_Operations/elementwise

¹) Hence the dot.

Comment: In [MATLAB documentation of Arithmetic Operations](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/arithmeticoperators.html) `.^` is called "array power" and `.*` is called "array multiplication", which may be useful to know eg. in searching for more info.

Answer (score 6):

There is a whole page in the MATLAB documentation dedicated to this topic: [Array vs. Matrix Operations](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/array-vs-matrix-operations.html). The gist of it is below:

> *MATLAB® has two different types of arithmetic operations: **array operations** and **matrix operations**. You can use these arithmetic operations to perform numeric computations, for example, adding two numbers, raising the elements of an array to a given power, or multiplying two matrices.*
>
> ***Matrix operations follow the rules of linear algebra. By contrast, array operations execute element by element operations and support multidimensional arrays**. The period character (`.`) distinguishes the array operations from the matrix operations. However, since the matrix and array operations are the same for addition and subtraction, the character pairs `.+` and `.-` are unnecessary.*