# What is the difference between * and .* in matlab?

Tags: matlab, operators

What is the difference between `*` and `.*` in Matlab?

Comment: See also [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10859917/what-does-operator-dot-mean).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`*` is a vector or matrix multiplication
`.*` is a element wise multiplication

```
a = [ 1; 2]; % column vector
b = [ 3 4]; % row vector

a*b

ans =

     3     4
     6     8
```

while

```
a.*b.' % .' means tranpose

ans =

     3
     8
```

Comment: `.'` (dot-apostrophe) means transpose in MATLAB. Just `'` (apostrophe) is the complex-conjugate transpose.

Comment: Hey @EitanT - that's my job to point out that `'` means `ctranspose` ! :)

Comment: @Nick if I do `a.*b` I get the same as `a*b`. In my code there is no `.'` Is `.*` useful in the absence of a transpose?

Answer (score 8):

`*` is matrix multiplication while `.*` is elementwise multiplication.

In order to use the first operator, the operands should obey matrix multiplication rules in terms of size.

For the second operator vector lengths(vertical or horizontal directions may differ) or matrix sizes should be equal for elementwise multiplication

Answer (score 0):

`*` is matrix multiplication while `.*` is elementwise array multiplication

I created this short script to help clarify lingering questions about the two forms of multiplication...

```
%% Difference between * and .* in MatLab

% * is matrix multiplication following rules of linear algebra
% See MATLAB function mtimes() for help

% .* is Element-wise multiplication follow rules for array operations
% Also called: Hadamard Product, Schur Product and broadcast
% mutliplication
% See MATLAB function times() for help

% Given: (M x N) * (P x Q)
% For matrix multiplicaiton N must equal P and output would be (M x Q)
% 
% For element-wise array multipication the size of each array must be the
% same, or be compatible. Where compatible could be a scalar combined with
% each element of the other array, or a vector with different orientation
% that can expand to form a matrix.

a = [ 1; 2] % column vector
b = [ 3 4] % row vector

disp('matrix multiplication: a*b')
a*b
disp('Element-wise multiplicaiton: a.*b')
a.*b

c = [1 2 3; 1 2 3]
d = [2 4 6]

disp("matrix multiplication (3 X 2) * (3 X 1): c*d'")
 c*d'
disp('Element-wise multiplicaiton (3 X 2) .* (1 X 3): c.*d')
c.*d

% References: 
% https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/times.html
% https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mtimes.html
% https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/array-vs-matrix-operations.html
```

Script results:

a =

```
 1
 2
```

b =

```
 3     4
```

matrix multiplication: a*b

ans =

```
 3     4
 6     8
```

Element-wise multiplicaiton: a.*b

ans =

```
 3     4
 6     8
```

c =

```
 1     2     3
 1     2     3
```

d =

```
 2     4     6
```

matrix multiplication (3 X 2) * (3 X 1): c*d'

ans =

```
28
28
```

Element-wise multiplicaiton (3 X 2) .* (1 X 3): c.*d

ans =

```
 2     8    18
 2     8    18
```

> > 