# plot Vectors must be the same lengths

Tags: matlab, plot, figure

Here is my code

```
po=0.21; %presuree of oxigen atm
ph=1;  %presurre of hydorgen atm
t=0.018; %mem tickness cm 
F=96487;   %C/mol
R=8.314471;      % gas confident J/K Mol
e1=-0.948;         %v act confident
e2=0.00312;         %v act confident
e3=7.6*(10^(-5));     %v act confident
e4=-1.93*(10^(-4));    %v act confident
n=2;      %number of electron
anda=14;   %landa
b=8;  %confident of V consentration cm^2/Amp
A=4; %cell active area cm^2 and i is current density Amp/Cm^2
r=0.2114
f=1;
j=1;
for T=333:10:363
    Co=((po)/(5.08*(10^(6))*exp((-498/T))))
for i=0:0.01:1
    v1(j,f)=-[(e1)+(e2*T)+(e3*T*log(Co))+(e4*T*log(i*A))]
    f=f+1
    end
    j=j+1
end
c=1;
h=1
for T=333:10:363
    z=(0.005139*(anda)-(0.00326))*exp((1268*((1/303)-(1/T))))
    for i=0:0.01:1
    v2(h,c)=i*(t/z)
    c=c+1
    end
h=h+1
end
d=1;
u=1;
for T=333:10:363
    a1=(1.1)*(10^(-4))-((1.2*10^(-6))*(T-273))
    for i=0:0.01:1
  v3(u,d)=a1*exp(b*i)
  d=d+1
    end
u=u+1
end
q=1;
for T=333:10:363
    E=1.229-(0.85*(10^(-3))*(T-298.15))+4.3085*(10^(-5))*T*([log(ph)+(1/2)*log(po)])
  V(q)=E-v1(j)-v2(h)-v3(u)
  q=q+1
end
T=333:10:363
i=0:0.01:1
plot(i,V,'-')
```

I want to have a figure that the X label is  i, the Y label is v and we can see change of V in different Temperature (T). but I face the error that "plot
Vectors must be the same lengths."

How can I fix this error?

Comment: How is **i** related to **V**?  You are trying to plot a 101-point vector along the x-axis and a 4-point vector along the y-axis.

Comment: I want to draw this figure: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/107043399/3r.tiff                 we know the v changes with i and T is constant , now I want show that effect of T

Answer (score 0):

Check dimension of your x, y vector by using `size(i) size(V)`. i should be a vector and the size should be [1 Len] or [Len 1]. Make sure the size of V is [Len, xxx] or [xxx, Len] too, so they are in the same length and you can plot it. Also, make sure i, and V have the same length 'Len' in the same dimension, otherwise you can use dot quotation operator,  `V.'`, to get the transpose.

Answer (score 0):

As Steven mentioned, you have a dimensional mismatch. Getting more familiar with a couple of the Matlab array operators (: and .) explained in the code can shorten and clarify the code.

Housekeeping before we get started:

```
clc % clear command window
close all % close all figure windows
clear all % clear all variables in workspace
dbstop if error % program stops in debugger if error occurs
```

Declare all your variables:

```
    po=0.21; %presuree of oxigen atm
    ph=1;  %presurre of hydorgen atm
    t=0.018; %mem tickness cm 
    F=96487;   %C/mol
    R=8.314471;      % gas confident J/K Mol
    e1=-0.948;         %v act confident
    e2=0.00312;         %v act confident
    e3=7.6*(10^(-5));     %v act confident
    e4=-1.93*(10^(-4));    %v act confident
    n=2;      %number of electron
    anda=14;   %landa
    b=8;  %confident of V consentration cm^2/Amp
    A=4; %cell active area cm^2 and i is current density Amp/Cm^2
    r=0.2114;
```

use T as a 1x4 and do that stuff first
all of these will be 1x4 afterwards
        T=333:10:363;
Notice the use of the [dot operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10859917/what-does-operator-dot-mean) to do pointwise operations

```
    Co = ((po)./(5.08e6*exp((-498./T))));
    z = (0.005139*(anda)-(0.00326))*exp((1268*((1/303)-(1./T))));
    a1 = (1.1)*(10^(-4))-((1.2*10^(-6))*(T-273));
    E = 1.229-(0.85*(10^(-3))*(T-298.15))+4.3085*(10^(-5))*T*([log(ph)+(1/2)*log(po)]);
```

Now let's do all the parts that involve i.
Let's not start at i=0 because that gives Nan/Inf results
        i=0.01:0.01:1;

If you wanted to, you could do this with section using matrix multiplication. It's implemented here with a for loop because that is easier to follow.

```
    for idx = 1:length(T)
        % each of these will be a 101x1 vector
        v1 =-(  e1 + (e2*T(idx)) + (e3*T(idx)*log(Co(idx))) + (e4*T(idx)*log(i*A))  );
        v2 = i*(t/z(idx));
        v3 = a1(idx)*exp(b*i);
        V(idx,:) = E(idx) - v1 - v2 - v3;
    end
```

In the `V=(idx,:)` line we are taking the 101x1 vector and shoving it into the idx row of V using the [colon operator](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2006/11/10/all-about-the-colon-operator/).

Now we can plot our answer!

```
    plot(i,V,'-')
    % now we'll do a little labeling
    hYLabel = ylabel('V');
    hXLabel = xlabel('i');
    hTitle = title('Your title here');
```