# what is the meaning of point(.) when division operation in matlab

Tags: matlab

what is this code meaning?

```
k = round(Q/12. + Q/123.)-1;
```

I couldn't understand why that `point(.)` needed.

That code is from `RSA code`. Part of calculating `coprime` number.

Comment: This is sometimes done to emphasize that this is a floating point number and not an integer. As MATLAB assumes a number to be double precision float by default I don't think this is reallly needed there. But I might be wrong on this one - any other opinions?

Answer (score 0):

The decimal point does not do anything here. It is probably the result of someone porting the code from another language with different data type conventions.

As hbaderts said, in Matlab the default numeric type [is double precision](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/numeric-types.html); other numeric types must be explicitly set. You can test this yourself:

```
>> x = 123;
>> whos x 
  Name      Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes

  x         1x1                 8  double
```

---

You will often see the dot (.) preceding the division,  multiplication, or power sign; there it means an [elementwise operation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10859917/).