# Octave - exponentiation with square matrix

Tags: octave

Why does in Octave the following

```
X = ones(10, 10)
X ^ 2
```

yields a 10x10 matrix with all elements set to `10`?

I was not expecting this but rather having all elements squared (and therefore a matrix of 10x10 `1` elements)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does operator "dot" (.) mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10859917/what-does-operator-dot-mean)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the ^ operator to be applied element-by-element, use .^

Otherwise you will be doing matrix multiplication.